# Не удается записать данные в mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Я создала простую форму регистрации. 
Использую struts2 и хочу чтобы когда пользователь кликает на submit -> данные отобразились в mysql database.

Таким образом я пытаюсь записать данные в датабейс:

```
public void registerUser(){


        user.add(username);
        user.add(password);
        user.add(email);
        user.add(picture);


        //connect to database
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            try {

                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myFacebook?" + "user=root&password=root");

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


         //Insert Data into database 
        try(PreparedStatement createUser = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into user(username, password, email, picture)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")){
                for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
        createUser.setInt(0, i+1);
        }
        createUser.setString(1, user.get(0));  
        createUser.setString(2, user.get(1));  
        createUser.setString(3, user.get(2));   
        createUser.setString(4, user.get(3));  

        int rowsUpdated = createUser.executeUpdate();

            createUser.close();
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Я решила создать `ArrayList` в классе `User`, потому что мне кажется так легче записать данные.

```
ArrayList<String> user = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Запускаю все свою систему через apache tomcat. Все запускается и не выдает никаких ошибок. Все методы и файлы между собой правильно соединены. 
Но когда проверяю датабейс в консоле, то данные не отображаются и мой столик user - пустой.

Никак не могу понять в чем ошибка. То ли данные с формы как-то неправильно вызываются, то ли я неправильно записываю их в датабейс.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. 
Заранее спасибо!

**UPD:**

```
 //Insert Data into database 
        try(PreparedStatement createUser = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into user(user_id, username, password, email, picture)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")){

            createUser.setInt(0, userid);
            createUser.setString(1, user.get(0));  
            createUser.setString(2, user.get(1));  
            createUser.setString(3, user.get(2));   
            createUser.setString(4, user.get(3));  

            int rowsUpdated = createUser.executeUpdate();

            createUser.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему проблема в этом участке кода.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   createUser.setInt(1, i+1);
   createUser.setString(2, user.get(0));  
   createUser.setString(3, user.get(1));  
   createUser.setString(4, user.get(2));   
   createUser.setString(5, user.get(3));  
}
int rowsUpdated = createUser.executeUpdate();
```

Здесь вы в теле цикла устанавливаете параметры запроса, но исполнение запускаете после выхода из цикла.

Вам нужно либо перенести в тело цикла строку

```
int rowsUpdated = createUser.executeUpdate();
```

Либо добавить в цикл строку

```
createUser.addBatch();
```

А после цикла вызвать

```
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

А `executeUpdate` убрать вовсе.

**UPD:**

Похоже дело не только в этом. 
Вот ваша строка sql:

```
"Insert into user(username, password, email, picture)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Четыре судя по всему строковых параметров. Вы же пытаетесь установить ей пять параметров, к тому же не соответствуя по типу!

```
   createUser.setInt(1, i+1);
   createUser.setString(2, user.get(0));  
   createUser.setString(3, user.get(1));  
   createUser.setString(4, user.get(2));   
   createUser.setString(5, user.get(3));
```

Выпадет `SQLException` на пятой строке.

Скорее всего ваше строка sql должна теперь выглядеть как то так:

```
"Insert into user(id, username, password, email, picture)" + "VALUES (?,?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Comment: Попробовала первый вариант - >  перенесла в тело цикла. Тот же результат. Я вот думаю, может я как-то неправильно добавляю. Я цикл создала - чтобы id добавлять. Пробовала уже разные варианты, никак не выходит. Либо user.get(...) просто не получает данные с формы. Я, к сожалению, даже не понимаю как проверить в чем именно загвоздка.

Comment: Я обновила свой код.

Comment: @Alex может у вас выполнение просто не доходит до цикла, а валится на попытке создать `PreparedStatement`? Есть ли возможность выводить ошибку из `catch` в лог чтобы его потом прочитать?

Comment: @Alex обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, вы правы. я немного изменила. и теперь у меня `java.lang.NullPointerException
 User.registerUser(User.java:94)`

Comment: В итоге все решилось. Спасибо большое!